# Can't build UIScrollView with Autolayout properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout, interface-builder

Can't build content inside scroll view with autolayout. Yes, I've investigated a lot, read apple technical note and some articles, I know, that content view should be constrained with scroll view's superview but can't still achieve the desired result. I expect this result:

1. fixed or scrollable (for small screens) portrait mode
2. always scrollable landscape mode, not to loose or overlap my fixed content
3. my button (red view) should always be at the bottom
4. my photo (yellow view) should always be fixed size and not to loose content
   (like in my wrong landscape mode)

[image]

Comment: So what constraints have you added and what does it do wrong (and when)?

Comment: Constraints you can see at the picture. The wrong is that it's not scrollable in landscape mode. Should I set up scroll view's content size in code? Could you advice some autolayot reading or gurus to learn? Because It's very often when I'm struggling with autolayout because of lack of knowledge about it. Thanks :-)

Comment: Pin the height of the contentView to a constant value! The scrollView should have a contentView based on which it decides the  scroll-able area. The content-View's width should be equal to the main view's width so that it is not scroll-able in the horizontal-direction but the height should be more than the view to make it scroll-able in vertical-direction.

Comment: you might find this useful https://theglowingtree.wordpress.com/2015/09/30/scroll-views-and-autolayout/

Answer (score 1):

Making this work is actually pretty easy. All you have to do are the following steps:

1. Add the `UIScrollView` as subview of your UIViewController`
2. Add the `UIView` as a subview of the `UIScrollView`
3. Add the `UIButton` as a subview of the `UIViewController`. Do not add it as a subview of the `UIScrollView` if you want it to stick to the bottom.

Then add the following constraints:

1. Pin the `UIScrollView` to the **top**, **left** and **right** of you `UIViewControllers` view
2. Pin the `UIButton`to the **left**, **right** and **bottom** of your `UIViewControllers` view
3. Pin the `UIButton` **top** to the `UIScrollView` **bottom**
4. Pin the `UIImageView` **top**, **horizontalCenter** and **bottom** to the `UIScrollView`
5. Set the `UIImageView` **height** and **width** constraints
6. Set the `UIButton` **height** constraint

And that's it. Do not add anything to the `UIScrollView` `contentView` and do not set the `contentSize` programmatically! The `contentSize` ist set automatically by Auto Layout.

Here are screenshots of the constraints and the result:

[image]

[image]

[image]